# Mostar Max y Minimo de salarios a partir de 3 tablas

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql, join, tablas

Estoy haciendo una practica con la cual uso la base de datos que proporciona mysql,  la consulta que debo de hacer es la siguiente: Mostrar el empleado que tenga el salario maximo y el empleado que tenga el salario minimo del departamento Customer Service.

```
+-----------+---------+
| salary    | emp_no  | 
+-----------+---------+
| max       | empleado|
| min       | empleado|
+-----------+---------+
```

Algo asi tiene que mostrar.

Las tablas son las siguientes:
Empleado:

```
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no     | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| birth_date | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| first_name | varchar(14)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name  | varchar(16)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| gender     | enum('M','F') | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| hire_date  | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Tabla para linkear departamentos y empleados:

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| dept_no   | char(4) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| from_date | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| to_date   | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Tabla de Salarios:

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| salary    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| from_date | date    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| to_date   | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Eh intentado esta query pero al no haber relacion con salaries no puede extraer el maximo y el minimo:

```
SELECT employees.first_name,max(salary),min(salary) FROM dept_emp INNER JOIN employees ON dept_emp.emp_no=employees.emp_no INNER JOIN departments ON dept_emp.dept_no=departments.dept_no WHERE departments.dept_name = 'Customer Service' LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: la consulta que pones que resultado te devuelve?

Comment: Nada debido a que no hay una relacion entre salarios y dept_emp

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a los amables comentarios de @David, caí en la cuenta, que estaba considerando que el departamento salía del propio `employees` cuando en realidad sale de la tabla pivot `dept_emp`. Entonces, ahora sí,  esta sería mi idea:

Los empleados con el salario mínimo y máximo se encuentran viendo la tabla `salaries`, como finalmente deseas saber aquellos de un determinado departamento, hay que agrupar estos valores por `dept_no`:

```
SELECT  d1.dept_no,
        max(s1.salary) as SalarioMax,
        min(s1.salary) as SalarioMin 
        FROM salaries s1
        INNER JOIN dept_emp d1
            ON d1.emp_no=s1.emp_no
            GROUP BY d1.dept_no
```

Tu segunda consulta, entiendo, intenta obtener datos del empleado con el salario mínimo y máximo pero de un determinado departamento. Por lo que podemos integrar el código anterior como "subconsulta":

```
SELECT e.emp_no,
       e.first_name,
       s.salary
       FROM employees e
       INNER JOIN dept_emp d
          ON d.emp_no=e.emp_no
       INNER JOIN salaries s
          ON s.emp_no = e.emp_no
       INNER JOIN departments dd
          ON dd.dept_no = d.dept_no
       INNER JOIN (SELECT  d1.dept_no,
                           max(s1.salary) as SalarioMax,
                           min(s1.salary) as SalarioMin 
                           FROM salaries s1
                           INNER JOIN dept_emp d1
                               ON d1.emp_no=s1.emp_no
                           GROUP BY d1.dept_no
          ) ms
          ON ms.dept_no = d.dept_no
          AND (ms.SalarioMax = s.salary OR ms.SalarioMin = s.salary)
      WHERE dd.dept_name = 'Customer Service'
```

Algunas observaciones:

- Nota que uso alias cortos de tabla, es más cómodo para nombrar las tablas luego
- A las columnas de agregación del `max` y  `min` es mandatorio darles un nombre
- Esto te asegura obtener uno o más empleados que tengan el salario mínimo y el máximo del departamento especificado.

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho, la primera consulta no proporciona el resultado que esperas. Estoy a la espera del dataset para poder realizar las comprobaciones.

Comment: @David, es cierto, interprete mal tu pregunta, quieres únicamente los casos con los salarios máximos y mínimos. Acabo de editar mi respuesta, verificala y cualquier cosa me dices. Saludos.

Comment: @David, recién caigo en la cuenta que no eres el autor de la pregunta, mismo nombre, mala mía.

Answer (score 1):

Empiezo aportando el resultado:

```
+-----------+---------+
| salary    | emp_no  | 
+-----------+---------+
| 1600      |    5    |
| 1200      |    1    |
+-----------+---------+
```

Y la solución:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT emp_no,salary FROM salaries 
      JOIN employees USING(emp_no)
      JOIN dept_emp USING(emp_no)
      JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM departments WHERE dept_name='Customer Service'
      ) c1 USING(dept_no)
  ) c2 JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(salary) salary FROM (
        SELECT emp_no,salary FROM salaries JOIN employees USING(emp_no)
          JOIN dept_emp USING(emp_no)
          JOIN (
            SELECT * FROM departments WHERE dept_name='Customer Service'
          ) c1 USING(dept_no)
      ) c2  
  ) c3 USING(salary)
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT emp_no,salary FROM salaries 
      JOIN employees USING(emp_no)
      JOIN dept_emp USING(emp_no)
      JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM departments WHERE dept_name='Customer Service'
      ) c1 USING(dept_no)
  ) c2 JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(salary) salary FROM (
        SELECT emp_no,salary FROM salaries JOIN employees USING(emp_no)
          JOIN dept_emp USING(emp_no)
          JOIN (
            SELECT * FROM departments WHERE dept_name='Customer Service'
          ) c1 USING(dept_no)
      ) c2  
  ) c3 USING(salary);
```

Así como un dataset con el que realizar las comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE employees(
  emp_no int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  birth_date date NOT NULL,
  first_name varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  last_name varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  gender enum('M','F') NOT NULL,
  hire_date date NOT NULL 
);
CREATE TABLE salaries(
  emp_no int NOT NULL,
  salary float NOT NULL,
  from_date date NOT NULL,
  to_date date NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(emp_no) REFERENCES employees(emp_no)
);
CREATE TABLE departments(
  dept_no int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  dept_name varchar(63)
);
CREATE TABLE dept_emp(
  emp_no int NOT NULL,
  dept_no int NOT NULL,
  from_date date NOT NULL,
  to_date date NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(emp_no) REFERENCES employees(emp_no),
  FOREIGN KEY(dept_no) REFERENCES departments(dept_no)
);
INSERT INTO departments (dept_name) VALUES
  ('Customer Service'),
  ('Sales');
INSERT INTO employees (birth_date, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date) VALUES
  ('1980-10-10','Juan','Romero','M','2010-10-10'),
  ('1985-10-11','Marta','Moncada','F','2010-10-10'),
  ('1980-10-12','Roberto','Iglesias','M','2010-10-10'),
  ('1980-10-13','Alberto','Pardo','M','2010-10-10'),
  ('1980-10-14','Laura','Tornero','F','2010-10-10'),
  ('1980-10-15','Miguel','Roca','M','2010-10-10');
INSERT INTO dept_emp (emp_no, dept_no, from_date, to_date) VALUES
  (1,1,'2010-10-10',DATE(NOW())),
  (2,1,'2010-10-10',DATE(NOW())),
  (3,1,'2010-10-10',DATE(NOW())),
  (4,1,'2010-10-10',DATE(NOW())),
  (5,1,'2010-10-10',DATE(NOW())),
  (6,2,'2010-10-10',DATE(NOW()));
INSERT INTO salaries (emp_no, salary, from_date, to_date) VALUES
  (1,1200,'2010-10-10',DATE(NOW())),
  (2,1300,'2010-10-10',DATE(NOW())),
  (3,1400,'2010-10-10',DATE(NOW())),
  (4,1500,'2010-10-10',DATE(NOW())),
  (5,1600,'2010-10-10',DATE(NOW())),
  (6,1700,'2010-10-10',DATE(NOW()));
```

El esquema de base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y los sucesivos pasos para llegar a la solución:

```
-- c1: obtengo ID del departamento Customer Service
SELECT * FROM departments WHERE dept_name='Customer Service';
-- c2: selecciono los salarios y ID de empleados de ese departamento
SELECT emp_no,salary FROM salaries JOIN employees USING(emp_no)
  JOIN dept_emp USING(emp_no)
  JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM departments WHERE dept_name='Customer Service'
  ) c1 USING(dept_no);
-- c3: localizo máximo
SELECT MAX(salary) salary FROM (
    SELECT emp_no,salary FROM salaries JOIN employees USING(emp_no)
      JOIN dept_emp USING(emp_no)
      JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM departments WHERE dept_name='Customer Service'
      ) c1 USING(dept_no)
  ) c2;
-- c4: localizo mínimo
SELECT MIN(salary) salary FROM (
    SELECT emp_no,salary FROM salaries JOIN employees USING(emp_no)
      JOIN dept_emp USING(emp_no)
      JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM departments WHERE dept_name='Customer Service'
      ) c1 USING(dept_no)
  ) c2;
-- resultado: unión de la combinación con el máximo y con el mínimo
```

Quedo a vuestra disposición para comentar o ampliar cualquier detalle.